# How Can I Use File class in an MVC Controller in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a little problem here. I'm using the following statement in a controller in ASP.NET MVC:

```
using (var fileStream = File.Create(path))
{
      stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
'Controller.File(byte[], string)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context
```

It seems that there's a function named File in the parent Controller class that my controller inherits from.

How can I tell the compiler that File here is a class not a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the full namespace to explicitly point at the correct `File` class:

```
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(path))
```